# Don't update version number with event Receiver

Tags: 2013, event-receivers

I have the following `ItemUpdated` event Receiver and everything in the code works.

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdated(properties);

    SPList list = properties.List;

    var approvalStatus = properties.ListItem["doc_approvalStatus"] as string;
    if (approvalStatus == "Final-Approved")
    {
        if (properties.AfterProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] == null && properties.BeforeProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] != null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            //This is triggered by events other than check-in action.
            SPFile file = properties.ListItem.File;
            SPListItem item = file.Item;
            properties.ListItem["doc_version"] = file.MajorVersion;
            properties.ListItem.Update();
            item.File.CheckIn("");
            //item.File.Publish("");
        }
    }
}
```

Except the part that when I use `item.File.CheckIn()` i wish to not update the version number.

If my version number is 42, and I run the event receiver it set the version to 43, I guess because of the `item.File.CheckIn()`. Is there a way to avoid updating the version number in my event receiver?

Comment: Can you try `properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate();`

Comment: It should not require you to CheckIn the file